# Change version constant before compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, compilation

I'm looking for a simple solution to find and replace a constant before compile. For example `@Version@` replaced with `1.0.0` so the program has access to the correct version `#s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to change your sources due to project limitation this might work for you:

assuming your version info is kept in a class named `VersionInfo.java`, the following snippet copies the original VersionInfo source from the default folder into a generated folder and processed the file with updating the version info. you compileJava task takes this generated file as another source and ignores the original one to avoid duplicate class name errors during compilation:

```
task preprocessVersionInfo(type:Copy){
    include "VersionInfo.java"
    from "src/main/java"
    into "$buildDir/preprocessedJava"

    inputs.property "version", project.version

    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: project.version])
}

compileJava {
    source preprocessVersionInfo.outputs.files
    exclude {
        it.file.absolutePath.endsWith("src/main/java/VersionInfo.java")
    }
}
```

Sidenote: This approach keeps the IDE setup as is, means during development you would keep using the unmodified VersionInfo class.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach than changing for source code is to keep the version info in a properties file in your jar. (e.g. `src/main/resources/versioninfo.properties`). This file can be simply changed during the build process by using the ReplaceTokens filter:

```
processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: project.version])
}
```

Then you can read this version info from a singleton class.

Comment: Yes, it would be a better approach. However, due to limitations of the project I have to use a constant that will then be referenced in an Annotation "@Plugin(Name, ID, Version)"